# How do i change a button color when it is pressed and to original when other button pressed. Buttons are created using class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im creating buttons using python class. Say it is having 10 buttons of same class. when i press first button color of first button should be changed to "red". when i press second button. Color of first button should revert to its original color and color of second button should be changed to red. Say now if i press 8th button then color of 2nd button should revert to its original color and color of 8th button should be now "red"

This is the class for the implementation:

```
class CreateButton:
    def __init__(self,Button_name,Data):
        self.Data=Data
        self.Button=tk.Button(delscframe.interior, height=1, width=28, 
                    relief=tk.FLAT, 
                    bg='light blue', fg="black",
                    font="arial 12 bold", text=Button_name,
                    command=self.OutputText)
        self.Button.pack(padx=5, pady=2, side=tk.TOP)       
    def OutputText(self):
        self.Button.config(fg='red',bg='light blue')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
Buttons = [] # list to store all buttons
class CreateButton:
    def __init__(self,Button_name, Data, index):
        self.index = index
        self.Data=Data
        self.Button=tk.Button(delscframe.interior, height=1, width=28, 
                    relief=tk.FLAT, 
                    bg='light blue', fg="black",
                    font="arial 12 bold", text=Button_name,
                    command=lambda:setRed(self.index))
        self.Button.pack(padx=5, pady=2, side=tk.TOP) 

    def OutputText(self, col):
        self.Button.config(fg=col)

for i in range(10):
    btn = CreateButton("name", i)
    Buttons.append(btn) # insert buttons into list

def setRed(index):
    for i in range(10):
        if i == index: # thats the clicked button - make it red
            Buttons[index].OutputText("red")
        else: # all other should be black
            Buttons[i].OutputText("black")
```